# Couldn't import input_data for 'MNIST' data set

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I'm trying to import input_data for 'MNIST' with the following code in jupyter notebook.
`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`

but the system shows the following error, pls help.

`NotFoundError: C:\Users\midhu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\_lstm_ops.dll not found`

Comment: Hi, Which Tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: the recent 1.7 version

Answer (score 0):

You can update the version in the TensorFlow environment of the Anaconda Navigator software. Perhaps you accidentally deleted the.dll file.[image: figure1] Another way is to import the mnist package using the Keras framework.
`from keras.datasets import mnist`

Comment: thanks, keras worked, but I dnt knw whats wrong wth `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`. dll file is not deleted I checked.